# Rails: Single-table inheritance with many-to-many self-join relationships between records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through, single-table-inheritance

I am modeling a learning web app with two distinct roles, `Teachers` and `Students`. There is a lot of common behaviour between both and it makes sense to abstract them to an `AppUser` base class. It also helps to use single-table inheritance for the two models, with a single table `app_users` storing both types.

Now a `Teacher` can have many `Students`, and a `Student` could be enrolled in courses by many different `Teachers`. So it's a proper many-to-many relationship. How may I model a many-to-many relationship between records in a single table.

I think one option is to use a join table on `AppUser` - something like `app_users_app_users`, with a `teacher_id` and a `student_id` column. What's the syntax to define this?

An alternative is to use a model, like `AppUserRelationship`, and then define `has_many through` relations. What's the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

this just an idea, create new relation table to hold many to many relation between

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: "student_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :teacher, foreign_key: "teacher_id", class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # as teacher
    has_many :student_relations, foreign_key: :teacher_id, class_name: "Relation"
    has_many :students, through: :student_relations, source: :student
  # as student
    has_many :teacher_relations, foreign_key: :student_id, class_name: "Relation"
    has_many :teachers, through: :teacher_relations, source: :teacher
end
```